# Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error given

Tags: arrays, bounds

I get an error on this piece of code, on line 5:

```
public static int[] greater(char[] num1, char[] num2) {
  if (num1.length >= num2.length) {
     int[] greater = new int[num1.length];
     for (int i=0; 1 < num1.length; i++) {
        greater[i] = (int)(num1[i]-'0');
     }
     return greater;
  } else {
     int[] greater = new int[num2.length];
     for (int i=0; 1 < num2.length; i++) {
        greater[i] = (int)(num2[i]-'0');
     }
     return greater;
  }
```

}

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: The code is supposed to copy the longer char[] array into an int[] array

Comment: Change  `1 < num1.length` to `i < num1.length`